# Value of sessions lost while routing URL's

Tags: php, session

I have index.php file where all stylesheets,js,etc files are included and i only change file in the content area of index.php using require once.Problem is that when user ask for some other page sessions are lost....and session variable is undefined...this is my index.php...while i access main.php , I am getting session variable undefined error...
----index.php file-----

```
<?php session_start();?>
<?php require_once("cc_includes/sessions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once('cc_includes/functions.php'); ?>
<?php require_once("cc_includes/sanitize.php"); ?>
<?php require_once('cc_includes/route.php'); ?>
<?php require_once("cc_includes/mydb.php"); ?>
<?php
    if($request_uri_header!='')
    {
        require_once($request_uri_header);
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <?php require_once("cc_includes/default_files.php");?>
</head>
<title><?php echo $the_title;?></title>
<body id="page1">
<!-- header -->
    <div class="bg">
        <section>
            <?php require_once("cc_includes/message.php"); ?>
            <div class="main">
                <header>
                    <?php require_once("cc_includes/logo.php"); ?>
                    <?php require_once("cc_includes/navigation.php");?>
                    <?php require_once("cc_includes/slider.php"); ?>
                </header>
                <section id="content">
                    <div class="padding">
                        <?php require_once("cc_includes/boxes.php"); ?>
                        <div class="wrapper">
                            <div class="col-3">
                                <div class="indent">
                                    <?php
                                        if($request_uri!='')
                                        {
                                            require_once($request_uri);
                                        }
                                    ?>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <?php require_once("cc_includes/footer.php"); 
                require_once("cc_includes/end_scripts.php"); 
                ?>
            </div>
        </section>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

-----sessions.php file------

```
$session_user=false;
    $session_message=false;
    if(!isset($_SESSION) || !isset($_SESSION['user']))
    {
        $session_user=array(
                's_name'=>'',
                's_gender'=>'',
                'college_id'=>'',
                's_joining'=>'Dynamic',
                's_department'=>'Dynamic',
                's_location'=>'',
                's_dob'=>'',
                's_approved'=>0
            );
        $_SESSION['user']=serialize($session_user);

    }
    else
    {
        //print_r(unserialize($_SESSION['user']));
        //exit;
        $session_user=unserialize($_SESSION['user']);
    }
```

-----route.php file--------

```
if(isset($_GET['url']))
    {
        $total_request=explode('/',$_GET['url']);
        if(count($total_request)>1)
        {
            $_GET['url']=$total_request[0];
            array_shift($total_request);
            $_GET['action']=$total_request[0];
            array_shift($total_request);
            foreach($total_request as $key=>$value)
            {
                $_GET['param'.$key]=$value;
            }
            unset($total_request);
        }
        if($session_user['s_approved']!=0)
        {
            if($_GET['url']=='' || $_GET['url']=='index.php')
            {
                header("location: main.php");
            }
            if(!is_file($_GET['url']))
            {
                set_error_message("No Such Location Exits!");
                header("location: main.php");
            }
            $request_uri=$_GET['url'];
            $request_uri_header="headers/".str_replace('.php','.h',$request_uri);

        }
        else
        {
            $request_uri="users/login.php";
            $request_uri_header=str_replace('.php','.h',$request_uri);
            if($_GET['url']!='' && $_GET['url']!='index.php')
            {
                if($_GET['url']=='services.php' || $_GET['url']=='register.php')
                {
                    $request_uri=$_GET['url'];
                    $request_uri_header="headers/".str_replace('.php','.h',$request_uri);
                }
                else
                {
                    if(is_file($_GET['url']))
                    {
                        set_error_message("You need to Login Before Accessing Other Site Area!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        set_error_message("No Such Location Exits!");
                    }
                    header("location: index.php");
                }
            }
        }
        if(!is_file($request_uri_header))
        {
            $request_uri_header='';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $request_uri="users/login.php";
        $request_uri_header=str_replace('.php','.h',$request_uri);
    }
```

----main.h file-----

```
if(!registered_user() && !admin_user())
    {
        set_error_message("Please Login To View The Page!",2);
        header("Location: index.php");
    }
    set_title("College Connections | Home");
    view_boxes(false);
    view_slider(FALSE);
```

-----main.php file-----

```
<?php 
   // if(!isset($session_user))
    //{
        //echo $session_user['s_name'];
        //exit;
    //}
    //print_r($session_user);
    //exit;
    echo"<h1 class=\"profile\">".$session_user['s_name']."</h1><h1 class=\"blue_profile\">'s Profile</h1><a href=\"dashboard.php\" style='float:right;margin-right:30px;margin-top:20px;'>College Dashboard</a><br /></br /><br />";
    echo"<hr>";
    echo"<div class=\"prof_image\">";
    $c_id=$session_user['college_id'];
    $image=mysql_query("select path from img_upload where username=\"$c_id\" limit 1",$connection);
    if(!$image)
    {
        die("database query failed".mysql_error());
    }
    echo mysql_error($connection);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't called `session_start()` in any file other than index.php so when the other pages are loaded the sessions are being lost

Comment: but files are included in index.php as the are called.....so why would i need to write session start in every file....and site is quite functional when it is live but when i run it on localhost i get this error

Comment: have alook at if($request_uri!='')
                                        {
                                            require_once($request_uri);
                                        }in index.php and it is manipulated in route.php

Comment: When you wrote "when user ask for some other page" this lead me to believe that you were referring to a page that is not included in the index.php file, in addition route.php looks like it will redirect users to main.php without content loaded into index.php when calling `header("location: main.php")`, try manually setting sessions and if that works then session create needs refinements because if they do work it means that the sessions are being re-written with no data. Sorry but I have to run now so I cannot help any further today but I hope this helps :)